# Knockout how do I set value in child observable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-mvc

I am trying to implement inline editing using templates. On my viewmodel, I have an method : self.changeMode. I am triggering this from a button click event ( inside the template). The data parameter that is passed to the changeMode function contains is the expected data but I need to change the observable. How do I do this?

```js
var MyViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.managingAgentId = ko.observable(data.managingAgentId);
    self.companyName = ko.observable(data.companyName);
    self.companyNumber = ko.observable(data.companyNumber);
    self.isActive = ko.observable(data.isActive);
    self.agents = ko.observableArray(data.agents);
    
    // Change to Edit or Display mode
    self.changeMode = function (data,event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // => need to change mode here!
    };
}


$(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: ma.Urls.LoadManagingAgent
        }).done(function (result) {
            $.each(result.agents, function (index, element) {
                element.mode = "display";
            });
            
            ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel(result));
        }).error(function (response) {
            addMessage(response);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script type="text/html" id="display">
    <td data-bind="text: managingAgentMemberId"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: applicationUser.userName"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: applicationUser.email"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: applicationUser.emailConfirmed"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: isActive"></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-bind="click:$root.changeMode">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
            Edit
        </button>
    </td>
</script>
```

```js
<script type="text/html" id="edit">
    <td data-bind="text: managingAgentMemberId"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: applicationUser.userName"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: applicationUser.email"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: applicationUser.emailConfirmed"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isActive" /> </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm kout-update">
            <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
            Update
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm kout-cancel">
            <i class="fa fa-stop"></i>
            Cancel
        </button>
    </td>
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean. applyBindings is being called on the   returned ajax?

Comment: I've deleted the comment ca 5 seconds after writing it, there seems to be some delay until you see the delete.

Comment: What do you want to change the `mode` to? Also, `mode` is not even an observable in your viewmodel.

Comment: I have 2 values being passed to the template - edit and display. So, when the button (on the agent row) is clicked, I want to change the "display" value to "edit" which hopefully will change the row to use the edit template. There is a second template called "edit"

Comment: OK - so setting the observableArray([data.agents]) does not use the "mode" property set after the Ajax call? So, how can I add this as a new property onto each agent?

Comment: No, an observable array does not magically turn everything in an object graph into an observable recursively (that's what the mapping plugin would do, if you wanted to use it, but I don't see you using it). I'd need to see your data model to set up a functioning example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107410/discussion-between-greg-and-tomalak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonical solution:

```js
function Child(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.mode = ko.observable('display');
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, Child.mapping, self);
}
Child.prototype.toggleMode = function () {
    this.mode(this.mode() === 'display' ? 'edit' : 'display');
};
Child.mapping = {
    // mapping rules, if applicable
};
function Parent(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.children = ko.observableArray();
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, Parent.mapping, self);
}
Parent.mapping = {
    children: {
        create: function (options) {
            return new Child(options.data);
        }
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new Parent({
    children: [
        {name: 'Child 1'}, {name: 'Child 2'}, {name: 'Child 3'}
    ]
}));
```

```css
td:first-child {
    width: 200px;
}
button {
    width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: children">
        <tr data-bind="template: mode"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="display">
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td>
        <button data-bind="click: toggleMode">Edit</button>
    </td>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="edit">
    <td><input data-bind="value: name"></td>
    <td>
        <button data-bind="click: toggleMode">Save</button>
    </td>
</script>
```

Comment: Accept but no upvote? Not that I would depend on it, but I wonder what's the rationale behind that.

Comment: just trying to plug your logic into my scenario - upvoting now

Comment: You've got me wrong, I was not so much asking for an upvote as for an explanation. I've been seeing that more than once, and assuming that "upvote" means "was helpful", I can't understand the message that "accepting w/o upvote" is supposed to transport.

Comment: My understanding is the person with the question accepts the answer and other that read the post and find it helpful upvote - ??

Comment: I see, that could explain it. I'm not sure if I agree with it, though. I see it like this: If something is helpful, upvote it. If something is not very helpful, don't upvote it. If something is outright bad, downvote it. If something is not very helpful or outright bad, don't click accept. (If you find yourself writing "Thanks" in the comments, upvote. Upvotes are the "thank you" of this site.)

Comment: I have applied your methodology to my code and most of it is working. The only issue is that the template isn't getting swapped on the button click but no errors are thrown. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was AFK. What was it?

Comment: Classic noob mistake with knockout - I didn't put the brackets after mode => this.mode(this.mode === 'display' ? 'edit' : 'display'); that was never gonna work

Comment: Haha! :] Lerning through pain, I guess. On the plus side, you won't make that mistake again, I'm pretty sure.